# Minecraft 1.12 crashes (java8)

Tags: minecraft

running Ubuntu 23.10
trying to start the pack "Ultimate Alchemy" via PolyMC using OpenJDK 1.8.0.392

from what I can see those old version dont like Wayland, and the Issue I can see is:
`[11:50:57] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper:<clinit>:72]: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/xprop": error=2, No such file or directory`
No UI appears at all and the following full log is shown: https://mclo.gs/svXfkBs

for referance I tried a Minecraft 1.19.2 pack (Skies Expert), using OpenJDK17 in this case, and it loads properly.

are the any fixes for Older java/minecraft version on new Ubuntu versions?

Comment: The error suggests you're missing `/usr/bin/xprop` which is a program in the `x11-utils` package. So what happens if you `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install x11-utils`?

Comment: I installed X-Utils ``` ll /usr/bin/xprop 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49776 Mar 25  2022 /usr/bin/xprop*``` still no change which was surprising to why the error is still `file not found` if its defenetly there and executable

Comment: PolyMC is obsolete. Try the tar.gz (not snap or flatpak) version of PrismLauncher from https://prismlauncher.org/download/linux/

Answer (score 0):

had to install `liblwjgl-java` manually via `apt`.
looks like at least `ultimate alchemy`(1.7.10) and `nomifactory`(1.12) are loading.